# How to keep a report in two separate access databases 100% identical

Tags: report, linked-tables

Here's the deal.

We have two departments with two completely different databases. Executives want a report to be printed out from both databases that are 100% identical. To accomplish this, the executives requested that I link my database to his and to create a single UNION query that combines the data so a single report can be generated off this data. This has proven quite difficult due to the difference in the systems, political considerations, maintenance considers and other factors.

The Executives are HIGHLY concerned with tiny formatting differences, which is why they won't let us create two isolated reports without the UNION query behind it.

Thus, my question is this: If I have a report in both databases, is there any simple way to make sure they do not drift in format? What if they were in the same database?

Comment: I'm guessing there is no way to do this =(. I always seem to ask the unanswerable questions, lol. Even confirmation or secondary tools could help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think to do this would be to use an ETL tool to create an interim database with a 'union' of the data from the separate databases. Then from there run the report using the reporting tool of your choice.

See the following link for an example of an ETL tool with some videos explaining functionality.
http://www.cloveretl.com/